# Regular expression to match userdeffields

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm looking for a regular expression that will match the following:

```
LiqUserDefField#(where#=1–2
UserDefField(#=1–18)
UserDefinedField#(where#=1–3)
UserDefType#(where#=1–2)
UserDefinedField#(#=1–10)
```

I want to return:

```
LiqUserDefField1
LiqUserDefField2

UserDefField1
UserDefField2
UserDefField3
UserDefField4
UserDefField5
UserDefField6
UserDefField7
UserDefField8
UserDefField9
UserDefField10
UserDefField11
UserDefField12
UserDefField13
UserDefField14
UserDefField15
UserDefField16
UserDefField17
UserDefField18

UserDefinedField1
UserDefinedField2
UserDefinedField3

UserDefType1
UserDefType2
UserDefType3

UserDefField1
UserDefField2
UserDefField3
UserDefField4
UserDefField5
UserDefField6
UserDefField7
UserDefField8
UserDefField9
UserDefField10
```

I've been playing at Regex101.com for a few hours now but I'm not making any progress. I'll embarrass myself and show what I've been trying so far:

```
\w+UserDef\w+\#\(\w+\#\=\(\d)\-(\d)
```

I'm using the Microsoft Regex Parser in Excel VBA.

Here is an example I came up with: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eE8qR8/4)

Comment: What flavor of regex are you using (e.g. PHP, Java, JS, etc.)?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention it. I'm using the Microsoft Regex Parser in Excel VBA. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LiqUserDefField[1-2]|UserDefField(1[0-8]|[0-9])|UserDefinedField[0-3]|UserDefType[1-3]|UserDefinedField(10|[0-9])
```

See it at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iH5cA2/1).

---

For a much more generic matcher (on request), you can simplify this to:

```
[a-zA-Z]+(Field|Type)[0-9]{1,2}
```

See this at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eE8qR8/1).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. While this does work, I'm looking for something more generic because I have other userdefined fields that weren't included and some of them I don't know what are yet. I don't want to recode every time I get a new set of fields.

Comment: That works great to match the userdefined fields after they are split out but I need to match them from the first set of fields in my post. LiqUserDefField#(where#=1–2 etc,

Comment: I've updated my original post. I've made some progress but still not quite there.

Comment: I'm just getting back to this now. Can you take a look at my latest regex and tell me what I can do to improve it?